# Trouble converting to a specific format C#

Tags: c#, byte, ushort

This may be a bit of a weird question, however I have made  a program which communicates with another program (the other program was not made by me). I need to send 'distances' to the other program, however I am having trouble understanding how the program is interpreting these distances.

I have intercepted a device which successfully sends distances to the program. Below is an example of a distance being sent. I think the program reads in a distance as a ushort. Hopefully there'll be simple thing I am missing as I cannot seem to be able to convert my distances to the same format.

For example:
Distance to be sent is 74. The bytes sent are [0, 74]. This as a ushort is 18944.

My initial thinking was the distance is converted ushort. Then the bytes of the ushort is sent to the program. However this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: First of all, stating multiple times that your question might be weird or stupid is not helpful.  There are no stupid questions.  But you have to do your research before asking a question here, and you have to show us what code you've tried so far so that we can look at it and potentially see any errors.  Please have a look at [ask].

Comment: Looks like the device wants little-endian, not big-endian.

Comment: `74 * 256 + 0 = 18944`; please, check order: `Little/Big` `Endian`

Comment: Apart from the endian type, how are you sending the distance to the other program, and how do you know that is not correct?

Comment: @Deolus They are sent as an array of bytes. I know they are correct as the program on the receiving end displays them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) that is the cause of the error:

- sender:   `74 (int16) == [0, 74]` - first high, then low bytes
- reciever: `74 (int16) == [74, 0]` - first low, then high bytes

And that's why the reciever gets

```
   0 + 74 * 256 == 18944
```

Try checking *Little/Big Endian* (i.e. *order* of the bytes):

```
   byte[] data = new byte[] { 0, 74 };

   // If the WorkStation uses Little Endian order, we have to reverse the buffer
   ushort dist = BitConverter.ToUInt16(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
       ? data.Reverse().ToArray() 
       : data, 
     0);

   // 74
   Console.WriteLine(dist);
```

Comment: Thank you this has been very helpful! - I have accepted the answer

Comment: Just a quick question, my program is written in C# and by default seems to be big-endian. The other program is written in C, do you know if by default that is little-endian?

Comment: @Lucy Copp: Endianness depends on CPU architecture (e.g. Intel x86 and x86-64 use Little Endian). Some CPU (like ARM, Sparc) allow to select the required Endian.